# Como aumentar a fonte no Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Estou começando a utilizar Semantic UI e queria saber se é possível modificar o tamanho da font, pois achei muito pequena e tive procurando no Settings do próprio site do Semantic e acabei não encontrando nada.

Quero aumentar a fonte das opções no dropdown.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI não requer nada fora do comum, da pra aumentar o [tamanho da fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) simplesmente usando uma classe CSS:

```
.cabecalho{
   font-size: 250%;
}

<span class="cabecalho"></span>
```

Caso você queira dar uma conferida em alguns tamanhos pré-definidos pelo próprio Semantic UI, [da uma olhada aqui](https://semantic-ui.com/globals/site.html#size).

Segue um exemplo de um dropdown que encontrei no próprio site:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="gender">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Gender</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para alterar o tamanho da fonte dos itens dentro do drop, simplesmente altero a classe css, só toma cuidado que esse código pode alterar em outros locais que utilizam a classe `.item` também, qualquer dúvida deixa um comentário aqui na minha resposta.

```
.item{
  font-size:22px;
}
```